# Is there any way of determining the value of k for selecting top k sentences in text summarization

Tags: python-3.x, summarization, textrank

I used the TextRank algorithm for ranking sentences of some articles. The total number of sentences in the articles range from 10 to 71. I wanted to know if there is any way of determining the value of k for selecting the top k ranked sentences as the summary. Or is that fixed to be some number?

Answer (score 0):

That's probably mostly determined by how large of a summarization you need.  In other words, if the summary must fit into some constraint (e.g., 400 characters or less; at least 50 words) then what's an appropriate setting of `k` to satisfy the constraints? Relatively speaking, it's similar to hyperparmeter optimization in ML.

Also, the quality will tend to be affected. Too small of `k` yields results that probably aren't effective. FWIW, I try to use `k >= 3` generally.  Too large of `k` and the results become less readable.

Comment: Thanks. So it is fixed to be a certain number according to our needs.

Comment: It may also be the case that you could vary the value of `k` for each document being summarized -- if there were criteria to use in that decision. For example, perhaps you wanted summaries of a certain target length, then you might iterate through a range to see which gets closest.